# How to add threshold to interstitial?

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, interstitial

I have a problem with interstitial. How can I add threshold to interstitial ?

```
private void setupInterstitial() {
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

    requestNewInterstitial();
}

private void requestNewInterstitial() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice("SEE_YOUR_LOGCAT_TO_GET_YOUR_DEVICE_ID")
            .build();

    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}


protected void bindViews() {
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    setupToolbar();
}

protected void setupToolbar() {
    if (mToolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    }
    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(mNavigationListener);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.hello_world, R.string.hello_world);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}

public Toolbar getToolbar() {
    return mToolbar;
}

protected void setHamburgerButton() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can change the frequency cap on Admob's website. Also, **do not show an ad when the user presses the back button**.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Admob -> Monetize Tab
2. Find the ad unit
3. Click on Edit
4. Set the threshhold (Frequency Capping)
5. Save

The edit ad unit page will show you this where you can set your threshhold.

[image]